# where can find good and in depth explanation for expectation, manipulation of expectation, sampling instead of expectation?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I look for a book or online source, for better understanding the expectation, expectation inside the expectation or sampling for calculation of expectation.
for example, in Richard S. Sutton's Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction book, equation 13.5 I want better understanding the procedure and how manipulation of the expectation.
[image]

Comment: One has to make extensive guesses about the meanings of the symbols, but all of this looks like nothing more than linearity of expectation and some algebra.  Linearity of expectation is explained in literally every textbook that introduces the concept of expectation.

Comment: @whuber thanks my source is http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf 
do you know a good textbook to suggest?

Comment: Readers of that book will want to have mastered the contents of a good calculus-based college-level course on probability and statistics.  There are many good textbooks to choose from.  You can search our site for threads that request such references.